# recorrer directamente la segunda columna con map

Tags: javascript, map

Estoy intentado recorrer directamente la segunda columna de esta matriz con map

```
var matrix = [
[1,  2,  4,  5],
[3,  1,  2,  6],
[4,  5,  6,  3]
];
```

he intentado con lo siguiente

```
matrix.map( (x) => x[2].map(x => x));
```

pero me da error , map no lo reconoce como una funcion, lo que me gustaria es recorrer la segunda columna sin tener que recorrer toda la matriz, se que puedo hacerlo con un bucle for pero me gustaria saber alguna manera de hacerlo con map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si muestras en consola:

```js
var matrix = [
[1,  2,  4,  5],
[3,  1,  2,  6],
[4,  5,  6,  3]
];

matrix.map( (x) => console.log(x[2]));
```

Puedes ver que está trabajando con un número, el cual no tiene el método `.map` de un array.

El primer map te da cada fila y al tomar x[1] obtienes el segundo elemento de cada fila:

```js
var matrix = [
[1,  2,  4,  5],
[3,  1,  2,  6],
[4,  5,  6,  3]
];

matrix.map( (x) => console.log(x[1]));
```

Comment: y por ejemplo si quiero acceder a una posicion dentro de la columna seria asi .. matrix.map( (x) => console.log(x[1][2])); por ejemplo

Comment: bastaría con `matrix[1][2]`, lo que hace map es similar a un `for loop` que te genera el: `matrix[i][2]`

Comment: te doy la respuesta como correcta